How does Liberty distinguish between multiple JSESSIONID cookies?
If a client browser sends more than one JSESSIONID cookie, how does Liberty determine the correct one for the particular application? The two have two different paths in this case, but one is the root path, so both are presented to the non-root-path application.
(FWIW, the root cookie's application currently has idReuse enabled, the other application does not. Which we can change, I'm just trying to understand the current logic to see whether this overlap could be related to intermittent session-loss problems we see.)

I suggest to set the cookie path to match the context root for your application.
This setting restricts the cookie from being sent to other applications and results in having different cookies created when accessing multiple applications.
<httpSession useContextRootAsCookiePath = "true" />

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_config_httpSession.htm
Liberty default cookiePath = "/", that is, the  slash (/) indicates root directory. Specify a value to restrict the paths to which the cookie is sent. By restricting paths, you prevent the cookie from going to certain URLs on the server. If you specify the root directory, the cookie is sent no matter which path on the given server is accessed.

We do this already, but one such app actually does own the root path. But the question is when this does happen - multiple cookies are sent - how does Liberty deal with that?

If the app own the root path, it will receive all the cookies.
Session is return if is valid else return null (assume getSession(false)).
I suggest cookieDomain if root path much be used.

This app that is receiving both of the cookies isn't the one that owns the root path, it's the one that owns a sub-path. But it's receiving both. So, the question is how does it tell which one to use? Can it get confused and try to use the root one instead of the path one?

The app has sub-path can receive root cookie. It will use both but the root one will not be returned as it wouldn't be valid.

So it what, checks both, gets nothing on the one but finds something on the other? I'd guess it's unpredictable what order it checks them in?

If useContextRootAsCookiePath is enabled on all the apps, it shouldn't have any cookie owns the root path.

One of the apps' context root is /

did you see my last addition?

The apps' context root is / will receive all the cookies that with cookiePath = "/".
Cookie belong to this app will returns, other will ignore.

You're saying that the app that is on context-root "/payment" and uses useContextRootAsCookiePath will ignore the JSESSIONID cookie that is from the context-root "/" app, correct? Which is what I'd expect, but I wanted to understand that for certain, as well as how it does that.
